# export a report in ms word(97-2003) without using RTFExporter in jasper reports

Tags: java, ms-word, jasper-reports

I have a report which needs to be exported in pure word format(97-2003) using jasper report. But Jasper uses RTFExporter for exporting report in doc format, wen i read the report using POI, it throws error saying its not pure word. Can anyone help how to generate a report in word using Jasper reports. Please help!

Comment: Where does the 97-2003 requirement come from?  POI can handle OpenXML (.docx) these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aspose.Total](http://www.aspose.com/categories/jasperreports-exporters/aspose.words-for-jasperreports/default.aspx) will allow you to generate .doc files from Jasper.

> Aspose.Words for JasperReports is the
>   only known solution on the market that
>   makes possible exporting reports from
>   JasperReports and JasperServer to
>   Microsoft Word document (DOC), Office
>   Open XML (OOXML, DOCX), Rich Text
>   Format (RTF), OpenDocument Text (ODT),
>   Web page (HTML) and plain text (TXT)
>   formats.

It looks quite expensive, though.

Comment: I'm thinking of integrating docx4j with jasper reports, which would provide an open source option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do anything closer than RTF from Jasper.  If you can't replace the Jasper report, then you need to find something that will read the RTF and render it as a DOC. 
You could use [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) to read the RTF and spit out a DOC.  Docmosis is based on OpenOffice and Java and OpenOffice has pretty impressive filters for saving in different formats.  Also, most platforms are supported since you haven't mentioned any limitations on what type of system you are running on.